# Difference between scale and balance

Tags: differences

Is there a difference between the word scale and balance or can I use both for an instrument for weighing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A balance is a particular type of scale where you put the item to be weighed on one side, and add weights to the other until you achieve balance. Scale is the more general word, and probably preferable unless you are specifically referring to a balance-type scale.

Comment: Even if it was a balance-style scale, people generally wouldn't say "Can you put these on the balance" or similar.  They'd use "scale".  This type of balance, as a word usage, crops up most in the phrase "checks and balances", I think.